# mongo $pull does not remove string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am sure I have incorrect syntax, so please see if you can help me remove an item from an array:

```
BaseUser.findOneAndDelete({
  baseId: req.body.baseId,
  userId: { $eq: req.body.username }
})
  .then(user => {
    console.log(`Deleted base with ID \`${req.body.id}\``);
    res.status(204);
    return user;
  })
  .then(user => {
    Base.findById(user.baseId)
      .then(base => {
        base.update({}, { $pull: { users: user._id } });
        return base.save();
      })
      .then(result => console.log(result));
  });
```

The `base` looks like this:

```
{ 
  created: 2018-09-05T19:28:06.947Z,
  users: [ 5b902e5448872a1da8b20536, 5b902f079f67030598f5dec0 ],
  messages: [],
  _id: 5b902e5448872a1da8b20535,
  creatorId: 5b7ee54ceb5ab41db89e04c3,
  title: 'testBase1',
  __v: 4 
}
```

`user._id` equates to `5b902f079f67030598f5dec0`. I am forgetting *something*

Comment: $pull should work for you with no issue. Check if your `user.id` should actually be `user.id.toString()` and also try instead of that to use `req.body.id` since that one seems to be `String` for sure.

Comment: @Akrion the idea of `toString()` is a great one, but does not work. `req.body.id` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

```
Base.findById(user.baseId)
    .then(base => {
        let indexOf = base.users.indexOf(user._id);
        base.users.splice(indexOf, 1);
        return base.save();
    })
```

The mongo methods of `$pull` etc do not work for me. Instead, I find the index of the deleted `_id` in the array, and remove that entry with the vanilla JS method of [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `{ new: true }`

```
BaseUser.findOneAndDelete({
    baseId: req.body.baseId,
    userId: { $eq: req.body.username }
})
    .then(user => {
        console.log(`Deleted base with ID \`${req.body.id}\``);
        res.status(204);
        return user;
    })
    .then(user => {
        Base.findById(user.baseId)
            .then(base => {
                base.update({}, { $pull: { users: user._id } }, { new: true });
                return base.save();
            })
            .then(result => console.log(result));
    });
```